# Sharepoint online run query on the Modified column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, kql, last-modified-date

In Sharepoint, I have the following library with the following documents + 1 image:

[image]

I want to be able to run a recurring query where I get all documents with a Modified time of 'today', every day in some script. Now trying a search in the search area like this:

LastModifiedTime="today"

Only gives me back the image.png

So I try something like this:

LastModifiedTime >= "2022-10-01"

Same thing, only the image comes back.

Now then I try this for several searches:

LastModifiedTime >= "2022-07-01" (nothing, only image)
LastModifiedTime >= "2022-06-01" (nothing, only image)

Then comes '2022-05-01' and suddenly, I get returned 'testimg.png', 'testdoc1.pdf', 'testdoc2.pdf'. Ok weird, so now I get back 2 of the three pdfs. Then 2022-04-01 nothing is added. 'LastModifiedTime

> = 2022-03-01' I finally get all documents.

Now these docs are named from different documents for which I don't know when they were initially added to Sharepoint, it's not like I created them today. However, I was thinking that the LastModifiedTime query would work on the time in the 'Modified' column, which now does not seem to be the case. My thinking is that it looks at something else, but how do I then run a query like this on the 'Modified' column?

I'm running the query from the GUID in my test library, like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you try using `Modified >= "2022-10-01"`?

Comment: Does also not work as I want it to, however, using LastModifiedTimeForRetention  seems to solve the problem!